# How do I make my UITextView autoscroll when dragging caret to the edge of view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uitextview

In the iOS's Notes app, I wrote very long text on the TextView,

then I long press on the view, bring up the magnifier loupe, drag it to the bottom of screen (or top of the keyboard, if it is activated), the TextView will automatically scroll up.

How can I implement this with `UITextView`?

**I tried**

- Add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to my `UITextView` subclass, but its action never get called.
- Override `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method in my `UITextView` subclass, but this method will not be called after the magnifier loupe appears.

Comment: what you want exactly?

Comment: @Sunny I want my UITextView auto-scroll when I drag magnifier loupe to the edge of view.

Comment: which method calls when you do that one?

Comment: @Sunny The problem is I can't find that callback method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't implement it; that's standard behaviour.

The magnifier scrolling occurs when you drag the magnifier off the bottom or off the top of the UITextView, or when you're close on the edge, about 10 pixels? (best to test this in the simulator where to have exact-control over the touch-position). If your text view is full-screen you may not be able to drag to a position outside the view, and the touch-region for scrolling may just be too small.

Notice in the Notes app that to scroll down you can drag the magnifier onto the tabs at the bottom. To go up you can drag it into the title. So long as you hold the touch outside the view it'll scroll.

All this also means your view can't go behind the keyboard when it's present. You need to resize the UITextView when the keyboard appears to get the scrolling to work.